# How get AJAX elements which XPATH is varying dynamically

Tags: ajax, selenium, xpath

In my application one AJAX filed which is displaying some values

When I tried to find out their XPATH it is varying dynamically

**for example :**

First time when I tried to find out the path it is giving it as `.//*[@id='ix-rt-13']`. When I refresh the page it is giving it as `.//*[@id='ix-rt-6']`.

Actually it is displaying 2 values one with id `.//*[@id='ix-rt-13']` and second one with `.//*[@id='ix-rt-14']`. And when I refresh the page it is giving XPath values as `.//*[@id='ix-rt-6']` and `.//*[@id='ix-rt-7']`.

I want to retrieve the second element text. How to do that ?

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="'ix-rt-15" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-focus" tabindex="-1">Being Powerful</a>
</li>
```

Comment: <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="'ix-rt-15" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-focus" tabindex="-1">Being Powerful</a>
</li>

Comment: Please understand that XPath is not a definitive thing. What you are seeing is that which ever tool you are using to generate Xpath is suggesting different Xpath.   Tool generated Xpath is NOT THE Xpath but IS A Xpath, and often not a very good one either.  You must create Xpath which solves your problem as suggested by Har01 below

Answer (score 1):

If link text does not change, you shouldn't use xpath rather use link text:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Being Powerful")).click();
```

However if you bend upon using xpath you may try following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'ix-rt-')]")).click();
```

But this would select the 1st element containing 'ix-rt-' in its id. So it may not work as desired if there are more than 1 such elements. In that case, if you know the index of element on page, you may use following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(@id,'ix-rt-')])[2]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can try this XPath :

```
(//*[starts-with(@id,'ix-rt-')])[2]
```

Above XPath will search for all elements with id attribute value starts with '`ix-rt-`', then return the 2nd result.